# Deriving the conservation of mass in a perfect fluid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

I have a problem on a homework assignment. I will write the question and then what I have so far. I just want some guidance on what I am doing wrong (or right). Any help would be greatly appreciated:

In these exercises we study the equations of motion of a perfect fluid. These are the conservation laws:

\begin{eqnarray} 
                    \nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu} = 0 \space (1) \\
                    \nabla_{\mu}I^{\mu} = 0 \space (2)
\end{eqnarray}

Where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the energy-momentum-stress tensor, and $I^{\mu}$ the particle current:
\begin{eqnarray}
                    T^{\mu\nu} = \rho{u}^{\mu}u^{\nu} + p((g^{-1})^{\mu\nu} + u^{\mu}u^{\nu}) \space (3) \\
                    I^{\mu} = nu^{\mu} \space (4)
\end{eqnarray}

Here $\rho$ is the energy density, $u^{\mu}$ the material velocity (a future-directed unit time-like vectorfield), and p denotes the pressure while n is the [article density.

Exercise 1 [Nonrelatvisitic limit of the conservation laws]: Let us first study the quasi-Newtonian limit of the conservation laws. We consider (1) and (2) in Minkowski space and assume that with respect to a system of stationary observers:
\begin{eqnarray}
                u^{0} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{|v|^2}{c^2}}}, u^i = \frac{\frac{v^i}{c}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{|v|^2}{c^2}}} \space (5) 
\end{eqnarray}

Moreover, we assume that 
\begin{eqnarray}
              \rho = \mu{c^2} + h \space (6)
\end{eqnarray}

where $\mu$ is the mass density and $h$ is the internal energy density.

(i) Derive in the nonrelativistic limit $c\rightarrow\infty$ the conservation of mass law,
\begin{eqnarray}
                \frac{\partial\mu}{\partial{t}} + \nabla\cdot(\mu{v}) = 0. \space (7)
\end{eqnarray}
Hints: Express the coponents of (3) explicitly in orders of c using (5) and (6), and derive the conservation law from the 0-component of (1).

So I have done a little work on this but I don't see how I can derive (7). Maybe there is some math trick I need to use or maybe this is a lot easier than I am making it out to be. So, I put (5) and (6) into (3) and I get the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
T^{\mu\nu} = (p + \mu{c^2} + h)\frac{v^{\mu}v^{\nu}}{c^2-|v|^2} + p(g^{-1})^{\mu\nu}
\end{eqnarray}
I am not sure what I am supposed to do from this point. I am not sure if I derived this properly and am I supposed to take the derivative of this in terms of $t$ and what do they mean by expressing things as orders of $c$. Thank you and have a great day!

Well after doing some work on my own in this problem I did get somewhere but not this question. I will show only the result of my derivation for at least one part and maybe more detail on the derivation of another part that is giving me trouble, but just to recall what I want to derive:
\begin{eqnarray}
 &&\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu0} = \partial_0T^{00}+\partial_iT^{i0} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

I got the first term just fine (I think):
\begin{eqnarray}
  \partial_0T^{00} = \frac{d\mu}{dt}c^2
\end{eqnarray}
but I am not getting something nice for the second term, so I will show my derivation in more detail:
\begin{eqnarray}
  &&\partial_iT^{i0} = \partial_i((p+\rho)u^{0}u^{i}+p(g^{-1})^{i0} \\
  &&\partial_iT^{i0} = \partial_i((p+\rho)u^{0}u^{i}) \\
  &&\partial_iT^{i0} = \partial_i((p+\mu{c^2}+h)u^{0}u^{i}) \\
  &&\partial_iT^{i0} = \partial_i((p+\rho)(\frac{\frac{v^i}{c}}{1-\frac{|v|^2}{c^2}})) \\
\end{eqnarray}
If I play around with this I somehow get:
\begin{eqnarray}
  \partial_iT^{i0} = \nabla\cdot(\mu{v})c
\end{eqnarray}
Which I don't think is quite right... any help would be nice :)

Comment: I think you mean $\partial \vec{v}/\partial t$ in (7).

Comment: Umm maybe... I am just writing what is written in the handout  and in the handout it is the gradient of $\mu{v}$

Comment: Oh my bad. It is correct.

Comment: It's fine, do you have any hints or anything... since I seriously don't know how to derive this?

Comment: ok let me post something gimme a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's homework I'm not going to solve this for you, but here's what they mean:

1) Taking the 0-th component of (1) means looking at
\begin{align}
\nabla_\mu T^{\mu 0} = 0 \implies -\partial_0 T^{00} + \partial_i T^{i 0} = 0.
\end{align}
Remember that $\partial_0 = \frac{1}{c} \partial_t$ and $\partial_{i=1,2,3} = \partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z$. So you can see the $\partial_t() + \nabla \cdot () = 0$ form of the equation coming out already.

2) In the limit $c \to \infty$, the term $v/c$ is small. That means we can Taylor expand the Lorentz factor in $v/c$. Recall how this is done: $(1 - x)^{-1/2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x + \cdots$. So this is what they mean by expanding it in orders of $c$.

So you should get stuff like
\begin{align}
(\cdots) + \frac{1}{c} (\cdots) + \frac{1}{c^2} (\cdots) + \cdots = 0,
\end{align}
Look at the term without any factors of $c$, that being the lowest order, and since $c \to \infty$ the other terms $\to 0$, the lowest order term should give you the continuity equation.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, I think this will be a really good start! I will write something up and hope I can do this!

Comment: Hello @nervxxx, I am handing in my assignment in about an hour, would it be possible for later on the day for you to write out the full solution to that question. I am pretty sure I got the gist of that question but I would like to see your solution. I know you can't really know whether I am asking for a full solution before I hand it in but I can assure you that I will have handed in my assignment before you write out a solution. If you are busy or whatever than it's fine, I will be discussing the other questions with my TA anyways but it would be nice to see the solution before then. Thanks!

Comment: well instead of me writing it out why don't you write it out. put it on some website (dropbox or google docs etc.) and attach the url to it

Comment: Well I was away for a while... so I am back to try to answer this question and I can give what I have so far @nervxxx

Comment: My background is Oceanography and never in my fluids classes have I seen this way of deriving the continuity equation, I was just curious where it comes from? What class is this?

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation Hello, this is a class in general relativity.

Comment: Am I that off :( ... I really want to understand how to do this.

Comment: @ InsigMath you're there... ok so I see you've implicitly assumed that $h$ is a constant. Also in the non-relativistic limit, $p \ll \rho$, which you've done. What you're missing is that, due to the choice that your teacher/book/assignment is using, time has the same dimensions as space, and so $\partial_0$ is actually $= \frac{1}{c} \partial_t$. That will solve your problem! I will edit my post to make that appear. Normally, I work in units where $c = 1$, so I don't have to worry about any such issues...

Comment: @ Isopycnal Oscillation : yea you've probably only studied fluids in a completely non-relativistic setting  (don't think ocean waves move at the speed of light, haha) so you've not seen the stress-energy tensor in such a form, I'm thinking. but one can model stellar medium as a fluid, and in this case it can move relativistically, so we need the relativistic version of everything...

Comment: @nervxxx thanks I really didn't know that $\partial_0=\frac{1}{c}\partial_t$. We don't have a textbook (although we did have suggested books) just lecture notes and the way this course was taught is very different then the approach you'd normally see in a textbook on GR. In any case thank you very much :)
Just out of curiosity do you work in GR in your own personal research?

Comment: @ InsigMath : no problem. I don't do GR research. I do condensed matter stuff, but GR techniques apply everywhere. In any case I'm still an undergrad.